# Determine colour from HSV histogram

Tags: c++, opencv, colors, histogram

I want to determine the colour of an object in an image. I was able to determine the mask of the object and generated the HSV histogram of the image using the mask.

```
cvtColor( Frame, hsv_base, CV_BGR2HSV );
int h_bins = 50; 
int s_bins = 32;
int v_bins = 10;
int histSize[] = { h_bins, s_bins, v_bins };

float h_ranges[] = { 0, 180 };
float s_ranges[] = { 0, 256 };
float v_ranges[] = { 0, 256 };

const float* ranges[] = { h_ranges, s_ranges, v_ranges };
int channels[] = { 0, 1, 2};
calcHist( &hsv_base, 1, channels, mask, hist_base, 3, histSize, ranges, true, false ); //mask is the mask of the object
```

Everybody shows a different method to do so.Can anyone tell me a simple method to determine the colour from the histogram?

Comment: I think [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#HSV_.28Hue_Saturation_Value.29) will help you

Comment: I have also found [this](http://mkweb.bcgsc.ca/color_summarizer/?faq) that may help you.

Answer (score 0):

When plotting the histogram, the X-axis serves as our “bins”. If we construct a histogram with 256 bins, then we are effectively counting the number of times each pixel value occurs.

In contrast, if we use only 2 (equally spaced) bins, then we are counting the number of times a pixel is in the range [0, 128) or [128, 255]. The number of pixels binned to the X-axis value is then plotted on the Y-axis.

Therefore, if you want to get the most common colour you need 256 bins (for a 256 bit image) and count the number of entries.

Comment: Do you mean I should use only two bin values each ranging from [0,128)?

Comment: Your question is unclear about what you actually want to achieve. "determine the colour" could mean quite a lot

Comment: I guess most relevant for color are the hue and saturation channels. depending on how you define "same/similar color" you would choose the size or the bins

Comment: I guess I could I ask it more simply.I want to basically determine the most basic colour's like red, green, blue, pink etc..I know the hue value can give these I colours, but I want to ask how can write a code for this?

Comment: if you split it up into 256 categories, you will get values for how many of each bin there are. For instance, if you have a completly pink image, and split your histogram into 256 categories you will have all your enteries in the particular value for pink.

if you have a complex image, the highest number will be the most common colour etc.

Comment: If you spplit it up into 6 categories, you will get 6 segments of the color wheel.